# Calculating the 3 largest colums in excel and summing them

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to calculate the total for the PT colums. I want it to calculate the top 3 PT colums and add them together. Excell noob so hoping someone can point me in the right direction. You can see my attempt in the screenshot below

[image]

Answer (score 2):

`=SUM(LARGE(IF(B1:P1="PT",B2:P2),{1,2,3}))`

which may or may not require committing with `CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER`, depending on your version of Excel.

Comment: The OP did not request a formula to be dragged down.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to Jos Woolley's answers which does not need the array formula entry as the function performs array operation is as follows:

=SUM(AGGREGATE(14,6,$B$2:$P$2/($B$1:$P$1=$S$1),{1,2,3}))

Note I set cell S1 to be a drop down list of possible column names instead of hardcoding the "PT" value.

[image: POC]

Answer (score 0):

Some alternative ways, to get the expected output, where you don't need to confirm press **CTRL SHIFT ENTER**, based on your `Excel` Version

**Alternative One:**

```
• =SUMPRODUCT(AGGREGATE(14,6,($B2:$P2)/($B$1:$P$1="PT"),{1,2,3}))
```

**Alternative Two:**

```
• =SUMPRODUCT(LARGE(IF($B$1:$P$1="PT",$B2:$P2),ROW(INDIRECT("1:3"))))
```

**Alternative Three:**

```
• =SUMPRODUCT(LARGE(IF($B$1:$P$1="PT",$B2:$P2),COLUMN($A$1:$C$1)))
```

**Alternative Four:**

```
• =SUMPRODUCT(AGGREGATE(14,6,($B2:$P2)/($B$1:$P$1="PT"),COLUMN($A$1:$C$1)))
```

[image: SUM_TOP_3]

Comment: Unless you have `Office 365` (in which case no formulas require `CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER`), you are mistaken about your second and third formulas, which DO require `CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER`.

Comment: I do not have a problem. I am on a public forum to answer questions and to correct others where I feel necessary. Likewise, I am happy for others to correct me where necessary. That's how a forum should work, in my opinion. That way people learn.

Comment: @JosWoolley Sir, thank you and sorry, but i have mentioned there as well! Anyways thank you for sharing your knowledge,!

Answer (score 0):

```
=SUM(LARGE(B2:P2*(B1:P1="PT"),{1,2,3}))
```

Also an Array formula. Leave cell with CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER